# Вывод названия и фото по ключу

Tags: java

Имею HashMap, заполненый значениями и ключами.

Нужно, чтобы при выборе ключа вместе со значением выдавало фотографию.

Например:

У меня есть список авто по индивидуальным номерам (123 - Мазда; 456 - Опель и т.д.).
Так вот чтобы при наборе ключа 123 можно было получить название авто и его фото.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Куда и как подгрузить фотографии, чтобы они были связаны с заполненым HashMap?

Comment: похоже придётся хранить один объект (фото) под двумя разными ключами( номер и название). Осторожно сделаю вывод, что нельзя хранить в ключе "опели-мазды". Т.к. значения в ключе должны быть действительно уникальными. Вот использовать регистрационный номер в качестве ключа - идея получше

Comment: Либо объединить инфу об автомобиле в один объект с двумя полями "Название", "Фото" и уже его хранить в мапе.

Comment: Хранить в мапе информацию вида: "Индивидуальный Номер" - "АвтоИнфо{Имя, Фото}". По номеру получаем объект "АвтоИнфо", из него фото.

Comment: @Rams666 Если ему нужно получать объекты только по номеру, то это единственный нормальный вариант.

Comment: @Rams666 Спасибо

Comment: @tarasula, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ну типа так:

```
class Car {
   int number;
   String name;
   Bitmap picture;
}

HashMap<Integer, Car> map=new HashMap<Integer, Car>;
Car opel=new Car(123, "opel");
map.put(opel.number, opel);
Car mazda=new Car(456, "mazda");

Car car=map.get(123);
System.out.println("Car name="+car.getName());
```